# Not being able to update(integrate) via PUT function

Tags: integration, netsuite, suitescript

I use Suitescript to integrate woocommerce and netsuite. I'm trying to update the products with woocommerce api, but it throws 301. Wherein, the GET function to this url is working fine. What should I be doing?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "fine"? 301 is also fine, it's redirection.

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean that I should be using a new url instead of what I use now? I don't see a new url in their documentation and also in the response.

Comment: Correct, that is what redirect is used for.

Comment: But, I am kind of stuck here; I have no url to replace the old one. I didn't see one in the response and in the documentation either.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't read that properly. If the new link is not in `location` field of the response, then there is nothing you can do.

Comment: So, am I out of options? I ask because I am able to GET the data, but not PUT the same. Is that not necessary be the same, the url for GET and PUT?

Comment: Different verbs can be (and almost always are) catched by different methods, they are separate.

Comment: are you sure woocommerce api is not the issue?

Comment: What type of Script did you build with SuiteScript? Where are you sending the request to?

Comment: @xpeldev I contacted the support and they directed me to the documentation. I again went through but was unable to figure out the issue. I'm not sure though.

Comment: @erictgrubaugh I'm working on Suitelet; trying to update the status of products from netsuite to woocommerce site.

Comment: If it is a suitelet then POST or GET are only mapped to context.method, not PUT

Answer (score 1):

Suitelets only support GET and POST. If you want to use PUT, then you will need a Restlet instead.